# makecontext not enough storage for stack

Tags: c, coroutine, ucontext

I try to make a header file in C that virtualizes all function calls from [ucontext.h](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/ucontext.h.html) library.

Everything is working fine except for function [makecontext()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/makecontext.3.html) when I try to call *my_makecontext()* I get this message:

```
not enough storage for stack: Success
Aborted (core dumped)
```

But when I use [makecontext](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/makecontext.3.html) instead of my function everything is working fine.

I am struggling to solve it.

A snippet of my code is:

test_file_for_my_funcs.c

```
//Doesn't work
//makecontext(&context.uctx_source,(void*)Write,1,*length);
//makecontext(&context.uctx_target,(void*)Read,0);
mycoroutines_create(&context.uctx_source,(void *)Write,length);
mycoroutines_create(&context.uctx_target,(void *)Read,length);
```

mycoroutines.h

```
int mycoroutines_create(ucontext_t *coroutine,void (body)(void *),void *arg)
{
makecontext(coroutine,(void *)body,1,(int *)arg);
if(errno != 0){
                perror("Error reported by makecontext()");
                return -1;         }
  else {
    perror("not enough storage for stack");
    abort();
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Never check `errno` unless the previous function failed. And the `makecontext` function doesn't (according to [this manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/makecontext.3.html) fail so you should now check `errno` at all.

Comment: Irregardless of if `makecontext` can fail or not, think about your logic for your error handling: Either there's an error, or else there's an error. You have no path in the function that leads to a "no error" situation.